# Debugging a BackboneJS click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is wrong. I'm trying to figure out the code that brings up the modal window. The modal window pops up when I click on a thumbnail. I right clicked on the thumbnail and selected Inspect element, and below is the code I got.

```
<div class="carouselItem thumbnail" data-id="id-470" data-type="document" data-automation="sectionCarouselItem">
  <img src="/assets/img/dsgd23.jpg" data-automation="resourceBoxArt">
  <div class="text_here title">
    <span data-automation="textTitle">Gandhi</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the right side of chrome dev tools while I'm in Elements tab(first tab), I clicked Event Listeners. I see different events like click, keypress, keydown, mousedown, mouseout, etc. When I click on let's say "click" event, I see body, div and document but beside it, it's saying jquery.js. I'm developing locally and I have source maps available and enabled. It didn't help me.

I also tried Chrome's Timeline but it's just capturing tons of things and I could hardly find if it's a click event, a mousedown event or a mouseout event.

Comment: I realize you are describing an issue you are having, but is there a question here? Your view is responsible for "delegating" events, and as you've included jquery, it will delegate through it. To debug the click event, you can use the "sources" tab in the dev tools and set break points on code which runs when the click event is fired.

Comment: after many hours of troubleshooting, I was able to figure out one but there is another one which is really complex.